# Failed audit for suggesting OP post on Code Review

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

[Audit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19480159)

IMO, as this is a question relating to a fully functional program, and solely interested in optimizations, it *may* have been suited over on the Code Review SE. I "posted" a comment stating that they should post over there, but did not flag it as off-topic. It was by no means the same as flagging, downvoting, or saying it was a bad question, just that it *may* be better suited elsewhere. Hell, I thought it was a decent question and tried to find optimizations myself.

Semi-related, *should* comments that are not accompanied by any other action automatically fail an audit? Comments, unlike other actions, are inherently freeform, and as such could be positive or negative. Last week I thanked a new user for their great question (with regard to formatting, what they tried, etc.). If that were an audit, should I have failed for that? Surely not.

Comment: Essentially....all comments on a review audit are a failure. It's a long *long* standing debate and complaint

Comment: Note that this question is not closed anymore.

Comment: note that it's not true in the low quality queue you get "cannot comment on audit". This doesn't fail the audit, this even helps you with it :) you should specify which queue you were processing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Whoops, forgot it doesn't show that. First posts queue, which I'm certainly not robo-reviewing, as I've already got my gold tag.

Comment: I didn't even know that commenting on first posts audit fails the audit. It's just stupid! first posts audit contents looks very much like low quality sometimes...

Comment: Code Review discourages migrations from Stack Overflow. Citation: somebody told me once, but they were pretty reliable if my memory serves me.